# How can I check whether the input string partailly matches any word in the given array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

For example my input string is

```
$edition = Vol.123 or Edition 1920 or Volume 951 or Release A20 or Volume204 or Edition967
```

How can I check the words in string matches any word in the array.

```
$editionFormats = ['Vol','Volume','Edition','Release'];
```

Basically I need to check whether the input has Vol or Volume or Edition or Release.

Can anyone please provide a way to check the pattern?

I tried with `str_pos()`, `preg_grep()`, `preg_match()`, `split()`, `str_split()` What I thought was to split the string after the first occurance of period or white space or numeric ,
but wasnt able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with regexp:

```
$edition[] = 'Vol.123';
$edition[] = 'Edition 1920';
$edition[] = 'Volume 951';
$edition[] = 'Release A20';
$edition[] = 'Unknown data';
$editionFormats = ['Vol','Volume','Edition','Release'];
$pattern = implode('|', $editionFormats);

foreach ($edition as $e) {
    if (preg_match('/' . $pattern. '/', $e)) {
        echo $e . ' matches' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $e . ' NOT matches' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/kfGXe).

Comment: Hi @u_mulder thank you for your answer will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is a single string (it wasn't obvious to me from the question)

A non regex way to do it is to look at the intersection between the set of words in the incoming string, and the set of words you're interested in:

```
$edition = 'Vol.123 or Edition 1920 or Volume 951 or Release A20'
$editionFormats = ['Vol','Volume','Edition','Release'];

// Break $edition into single words on, on space character.
$edition_words = explode(" ", $edition);

$present = !empty(array_intersect($edition_words, $editionFormats));
```

If you had meant that the $edition would be just one of those;
i.e.

```
$edition = 'Volume 951'
```

This approach will still work;  Note that splitting on the space character only works if there is a space, so your 'Vol.123' wouldn't get matched, unless you also included 'Vol.' in your $editionFormats.

Comment: Hi @Howard Thanks for the answer.My input is string. This was one of the way I tried the problem is it doesn't work for Edition123 or Volume986 . That's the reason I am trying to split it on occurance of period or space or numeric.Is there a way to explode on occurance of dot or space or number?

Comment: explode doesn't take more than one parameter to explode on, which is a pain in this case.  Your other approach is to iterate over $edition_words and test to see if any are in your input string using strpos, that way you don't need to worry about having to split on identifiers.